# Where do I add css into jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I already added :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="show_style.css" />
```

in my header in html.  I am not sure Where do I add css into jsp?

[image: snapshot for the structure of jsp]

Comment: Have you tested it out? If yes, please state what problem you are having that cause you to ask this question. If no, please test it out first.

Comment: @sara0832, where is your CSS located? I which folder?

Answer (score 0):

JSP is can be thought like Java within HTML.  So, you will be having HTML & JSP code like this:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>    
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="show_style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>     
  <%   
   //JSP code.
   %>
  </body>    
 </html>
```

OR;

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="show_style.css" />
<% 
//JSP Code
%>
```

---

You can put/store css anywhere as per your project design, say as you are storing in `lib` folder the following changes need to be done in JSP.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../WEB-INF/lib/show_style.css" />
```

I would suggest you to create a new folder named as `resources` inside the `WebContent` folder, and to store your external css inside `css` folder under  `resources`, So that it will be easy to maintain the css.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/show_style.css" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I added the css in the lib and it works.  I almost tried every place but lib before I asked this question.

Comment: For better solution, you should create a servlet or a filter to resolve your resource request.

Comment: You need to create a style folder and link it with style folder. It is the common practice. Do not put `css` files inside lib folder. lib folder is generally used to add `jar` files and libraries. What you are doing is a wrong practice.Inside webcontent folder create style folder inside that put your css file and call it like this `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style/show_style.css" />`